# Converting video to gif: how to ensure playback is the same speed when using 60 fps videos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, video

I would like to use videos captured at 60 FPS (or possibly 30) for my gifs. The software I'm using to convert videos to gifs is Adobe Photoshop.

Problem is that those frame rates don't work very well for gifs. The delay time for each frame in the gif would either be rounded up or down to the nearest hundredth. This causes the playback to either be slower or faster. I would like it to play at the same speed.

What are my solutions?

I am temporarily recording my videos at 50 FPS but I would prefer to record at 60 fps.

Perhaps there is software that can set a variable delay so that the overall duration isn't affected? Photoshop just sets the same delay for every frame.

Comment: If your hardware can handle a 60fps GIF, it _will_ playback at 60fps, it has nothing to do with the file type or capture speed.

Comment: @Luciano When you save a 60 fps video in Photoshop as a gif, it sets the delay time to 0.02 seconds per frame. This would make the gif playback slower than the video. A solution would be to set the delay to 0.01s for the 1st, 0.02s for the 2nd and 3rd frames, and repeat that for the rest of the frames. But that is too much manual work.